# Unable to launch nodemon environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nodemon

I'm trying to start my server with `nodemon`, but it crashes with the following output.

The error `ERROR: Unrecognized environment. Aborting.` seems quite rare, from [a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodemon%20%22ERROR%3A%20Unrecognized%20environment.%20Aborting.%22).

Ran the same code in Windows 10 and a WSL2 Ubuntu set up. Both had the same results. The server does start for my coworker for some reason, though.

```
user@LAPTOP:~/myproject$ npm run start:dev

> myproject@0.0.0 start:dev /home/user/myproject
> nodemon

[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts,html
[nodemon] starting `./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src`
[2021-03-23T04:11:42.704Z] ERROR: Unrecognized environment. Aborting.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
^C
user@LAPTOP:~/myproject$ npm -v
6.14.11
user@LAPTOP:~/myproject$ node -v
v15.12.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a bug with my sequelize code**

The issue came from trying to access the `sequelize.js` database before connecting to it.

Moving my `Model.findAll()` statement to after the app has launched has fixed the issue.